# Locale Change event in Win8 App

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Is there any locale change event that we can use in Win8 applications?

The problem I have right now is when you change your language in control panel while the app is running, the app will pick up the new language right away. This result in the app pages that's not being refreshed are still stays in old language and when you go to another page of the application, it will load the strings in new language.

Does anyone have any insight on this? I am using HTML5 and Javascript, but any knowledge will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Events and context changes. Metro style apps may still be running when
>   the system changes. This results in a different set of qualifiers
>   being used. One such change might be when the user turns on high
>   contrast. Various system changes invoke events on the ResourceContext
>   object. In JavaScript, the simplest way to listen for these events is
>   through JavaScript
>
> WinJS.Resources.addEventListener('contextchanged', refresh, false);

Here is the article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465248.aspx